# How to secure an endpoint that is accessed by unauthenticated users in a serverless application

Tags: node.js, security, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

We have an endpoint that needs to be queried for the pool Id for a given tenant before the user's login request can be sent. What is the best way to "secure" such an endpoint that is open for access by unauthenticated users?

We are using API gateway and lambda functions and serverless framework.

Comment: Can the pool lookup be done from the backend?

Comment: we are doing it from the backend but want it up to the front-end to log the user in using Amplify. @Matt

Comment: By `pool Id`, do you mean the Cognito User Pool Id?  You say you are using Amplify, but don't specifically say if you're using Cognito for auth.  

Can you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: @SethGeoghegan Cognito pool Id, yes. We are using Cognito user pools for authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Cognito Identity Pools have an option that may work for you.  First, I'll quickly cover the differemt Cognito services, since it's something that confused me when I was first trying to understand Cognito.

At the risk of oversimplifying, AWS Cognito exists to answer two questions:

1. Who are you? (authentication)
2. What can you do? (authorization)

Cognito addresses these concerns with two distinct offerings: User Pools (authentication) and Identity Pools (authorization).

You can think of Cognito User Pools as your application's user directory. At a high level, User Pools let you handle user registration, authentication, account recovery, and supports authentication with third-party identity providers like Facebook, Google, etc.

Cognito Identity Pools provides a way to authorize users to use various AWS services. You can think of it as a vending machine for handing out AWS credentials. For example, if you needed to give your users access to upload a file to an S3 bucket or to invoke an endpoint in API Gateway, you could do so with an Identity Pool.

Here's a handy illustration to describe what I've outlined above.

[image]

Cognito lets you support unauthenticated users in your Identity Pool ([instructions here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html)).

So, how does this apply to your question?

You can use Cognito to enable IAM authorization across your *entire* API, which allows you to leverage the power of IAM to control access to your API.  When you enable unauthenticated user access in Cognito, guest visitors to your site will be assigned to the *unauthenticated* IAM user role.  Users that log in to your site will be assigned to the *authenticated* IAM user role.  You can attach IAM policies to these roles that define what each role has access to.

For example, you might want to restrict unauthenticated users to certain API endpoints.  On the other hand, authenticated users might get access to invoke *all* API endpoints in your application.